# Git push to main project repo throws an error after git subtree add

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push, git-subtree

Trying to use git subtree to share common library files across multiple projects. Here's the problem I keep encountering.

1) Add subtree so "jquery_treetable" subdirectory of my project.

```
$ git subtree add -P jquery_treetable ssh://epedgov@gerrit.ericsson.se:29418/global_share/3pp/foss/jquery_treetable master --squash
```

gitk looks like below after subtree add

[image: gitk]

2) push updates to main project repo(Gerrit)

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
remote: ERROR: [36fb8f5] missing Change-Id in commit message footer
remote: 
remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 epedgov@gerrit.ericsson.se:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
remote: And then amend the commit:
remote:   git commit --amend
remote: 
To https://gerrit.ericsson.se/a/lte/tools/mkdoc
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master ([36fb8f5] missing Change-Id in commit message footer)
```

3) git log looks like below

[image]

4) I think, I get this rejection because of change-id is missing in 2nd commit in git log (Squashed one). But how to add Change-id for this Squashed subtree.

Comment: One tricky case could be change ID is always expected to be at the last line of the commit message

Comment: @prudviraj Updated the question. check once again

Answer (score 0):

You have two un merged commits ( The commit Date is same for both commits, so i guess both are created at the same time and are not merged ) and the issue is not with first commit , it is with second commit ( Error message shows that `36fb8f5`) which had git-subtree in commit message and change-Id is missing , gerrit will check for change id of all changes which are to be merged, you might need to a

`git reset --soft HEAD^1` ( If you want previous changes of merge commit )

However if you want to resolve issue at hand and have a clean slate

`git reset --hard HEAD^1`

Above command should now bring you branch HEAD position to  `36fb8f5`

you can check the same using

```
git log -2
```

Now perform

`git commit --amend`

Now check if the change Id got append to the commit message , if it is , you can push the change and issue should be resolved